# How to send email with HTML body in Flutter's web?

Tags: flutter, dart, email, flutter-web, mailer

I am using the `mailer` package. However, the `mailer` package does not support web. Suddenly I thought that the package `url_launcher` can send emails and support the web.

However, I have a question, how can I make the body `HTML`? Or is this not a solution for sending emails with `HTML` body?

I didn't include the code because I don't think the code has anything to do with this.

If you need more info feel free to leave a comment!

How to send email with `HTML` body in Flutter's web? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by `send email with HTML body` ?

Comment: @eamirho3ein that means the body is `HTML` like `<h1>HTML</h1>`

Comment: you can put any string in it, but it won't parse it and show the result of you html tags, it just show then as string.

Comment: @eamirho3ein so, how do I display the `HTML` styled results?

Comment: sorry nothing get to my mind to do that. @MyCar

Comment: @eamirho3ein that's okay. However, thank you for taking the time to reply to me

Answer (score 0):

For a few of my recent projects built for web I was using firebase, and could simply add the Firebase Mail Extension, which allows you to push a document to a specific collection with data such as the target email address, subject, and body (included HTML). The extension then triggers the email to be sent through SMTP.
[Read more about it here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-send-email)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've read the documentation, but I have a problem, the programming language of the code doesn't look like the `Flutter` programming language. How to send email with `HTML` body in ***Flutter***'s web?

Comment: That is due to the documentation link being for the email extension. As mentioned in the article, in order to trigger the email being sent (the part where you need to use flutter to interact with firestore, triggering the extension) is done by creating a document in the mail collection. You can find documentation for writing to firestore seperately

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/
May be of use if you are wondering how to write to firestore. This is only used once you have configured the extension as in the previously attach documentation

Comment: Where should I write the code in the documentation?

Comment: Please see the ‘Pre-installation setup’ instructions on the original link

Comment: Will take a look at it. I will get back to you if there are any updates

Comment: Sure. If not I’ll be happy to write out a guide for you to set up emails

Comment: Much appreciated. In fact together with this documentation, I also start looking for similar guided article or YT content

Comment: Thanks. Hope my answer answered your question